# Trying to Query the Google Search Console API for a specific URL

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-search-console, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to get results for a specific URL but only get the base URL result, not sure why my query doesn't query the specific URL?

i.e. result of query is for my-domain.co.uk, not my-domain.co.uk/pizza/2 as expected.

```
    const url = "https://www.my-domain.co.uk/pizza/2"
    
    searchconsole.searchanalytics.query(
            {
              siteUrl: "https://www.my-domain.co.uk",
              requestBody: {
                startDate: "2023-01-01",
                endDate: "2023-01-01",
                dimensions: ["page"],
                filters: [
                  {
                    dimension: "page",
                    operator: "equals",
                    expression: url,
                  },
                ],
                startRow: 0,
                rowLimit: 1,
              },
            },
            async (err, response) => {
              console.log(response);
              if (err) return res.status(500).send(`Error: ${err}`);
              res.send(response.data);
            }
          );
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is causing your problem, but your URL is not part of the site. You are missing the `www.` from the query URL despite having it in the `siteUrl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only Googles docs were easier to navigate. The issue appears to be that I should have been using the 'dimensionFilterGroups' key.

```
 searchconsole.searchanalytics.query(
    {
      siteUrl: process.env.SITE_URL,
      requestBody: {
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: endDate,
        dimensions: ["page"],
        dimensionFilterGroups: [
          {
            groupType: "and",
            filters: [
              {
                dimension: "page",
                operator: "equals",
                expression: url,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
        aggregationType: "byPage",
        
        startRow: 0,
        rowLimit: 1,
      },
    },
    async (err, response) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).send(`Error: ${err}`);
      res.send(response.data);
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason is that the url variable contains the full URL, including the path "/pizza/2". In the searchconsole.searchanalytics.query method, the siteUrl parameter is set to https://www.my-domain.co.uk, which only includes the domain name and not the path. Therefore, the query is only searching for pages that match the domain name my-domain.co.uk and not the specific URL my-domain.co.uk/pizza/2. To get the expected result, you should set the siteUrl parameter to https://my-domain.co.uk instead of https://www.my-domain.co.uk.

Comment: Sorry that's my mistake, I messed that up when making changes to my code to show the example.